# Two applications with single domain

Tags: apache, nginx, puma

I have two applications. 1) Angular 5 as Front-end and 2) Ruby on Rails as Front-end as well as back-end.

Angular 5 domain like - http(s)://www.xyz.net/ and For Ruby on Rails domain like - http(s)://www.xyz.net/blogs.

I can do with the sub-domain but I want in single domain without sub-domain including SSL.

Is this possible ? If yes then How can I do this ?

Please Guide

Comment: You tagged your question with apache, so it should be doable with the apache conf. You can as well alter the `host` file of your system, if run into a vps. As a third option, by using caddy server: see https://caddy.community/t/multiple-domains/1761

Answer (score 1):

You can setup like below in the nginx (/etc/site-enabled folder)

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/;

  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name _;

  location /blogs/ {
    # Blog Project - Ruby on Rails
    alias /var/www/PROJECT-2;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/PROJECT-2;
  }

  location / {
    # Angular Project 
    alias /var/www/PROJECT-1/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/PROJECT-1/;
  }
}
```